# Rails 6: Dynamically create/switch/migrate database from form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, migration

First off Is this possible ?? 
Let's say we have an organization and we want to segregate the database for each of the organizations dynamically. 
**Case 1** 
If the admin wants to create an organization if the database for that organization already exists. No further tasks.
**Case 2** 
If the admin wants to create an organization if the database for that organization does not exist. Create a new database and run the migrations according to the list of migrations that we have. Database name would be the name of that particular organization fetched from the form input.

**Result**
Later on whenever the organization logins through our app. The database needs to be switched according to the organization. 
Again is it possible? It would be a big help if somebody answers this or provides a hack to achieve it. 
**Rails version: 6.1.4.1** 
**Database: Postgresql**

Comment: Sure, you can close the old connection and open a new one. And there is a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

Comment: I was thinking that first but Rails 6 provides the `connects_to` method on the model and we are using it right now(we have couple of databases). The name for the databases are static and also `connects_to` requires information provided in `database.yml`. In our case, everything needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

In the organization class you need to call [establish_connection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection)

For example

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  "mysql2",
  host:     "localhost",
  username: "myuser",
  password: "mypass",
  database: "somedatabase"
)
```

If you use devise and want to set the organization after the user logs in, you can use the [after_set_user](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Callbacks#after_set_user) callback

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user, auth, opts|
  # connect to database
end
```

Comment: Will defo look at this. Thank you brother :) 
Btw How do I make dynamic database ? I don't want it connect to pre existing one.

Comment: There needs to be a single pre existing default database that Rails can connect to when the server starts. All other databases can be dynamic. I store all the dynamic databases in a table in the default database and switch in the after_set_user callback.